Get simulated state from statsmodels.tsa.statespace
The command statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEModel.simulate() provides you with simulated observations based on the state space model. But, can we get the simulated state?
Docs of simulate function are here: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEModel.simulate.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEModel.simulate
I have a hack solution, but I am wondering is there a better way to do this.
In order to get the states we can use a seeded simulation of the observations. Say amod is an instance of a tsa.MLEmodel. First we need to set the observation covariance to zero.
amod.ssm.obs_cov *= 0

Then, each coordinate of the state can be retrieved with a suitable selection of the design matrix. In the case below, the observations were 1D while the state is 3D, so the design matrix is a 3-vector. So a time-constant design matrix (1,0,0) would recover the first coordinate of the state, (0,1,0) would recover the second coordinate and so on. Thus the need to reproduce the simulation and the need of the random seed.
for i in range(amod.k_states):
    for j in range(amod.k_states):
        if j==i:
            amod.ssm.design[:,j] *= 0
            amod.ssm.design[:,j] += 1
        else:
            amod.ssm.design[:,j] *= 0
    auxi.append(amod.simulate(params, 
nsimulations=amod.nobs,random_state=100))
simulated_state = np.r_[auxi]

